# Smooth quantile estimation algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, quantile

I came across the paper of M. C. Jones on smooth quantile estimation ([link](http://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/044_4_0721.pdf)). He proposes using the following estimator for quantile function Q around point p (first equation of Section 2). I tried to code the function in R but the estimates are quite far from the empirical quantiles.

For a univariate sample X, bandwidth h and quantile p the code goes

```
SmoothQuantile = function(x, h, p) {
xs = sort(x)
n  = length(x)
q  = 0
for(i in 1:n) {
   q = q + xs[i] * integrate(function(y) { 1/h * dnorm((p-y)/h) }, lower = (i-1)/n, upper = i/n)$value
}
return(q)
}
```

It seems a quite straightforward implementation of the estimator above. Any ideas what can be potentially driving the results so far away from the empirical quantiles?

To compare the results use

```
x=rnorm(100, 0, 1)
p=0.01
h=0.3043                #normal scale bandwidth value
quantile(x, p)          #empirical quantile
SmoothQuantile(x, h, p) #smooth quantile
```

Comment: I might have looked at the wrong equation but I didn't see a density function or bandwidth in it and I also don't know how you derive the bandwidth, which has an obvious impact on the result.

Comment: Density function is taken as a kernel function. The bandwidth is just a smoothing parameter, calculated for a standard normal sample of size 100. It shouldn't have such a big influence on the results. Especially, that if you increase the sample, and adjust the bandwidth accordingly, the problem still persists.

Comment: I see a huge impact if I change the value of `h`.

Comment: To what value do you change it?